# How do I copy a local home dir to an iscsi mounted home directory

Tags: kernel, cp, iscsi

I have various Ubuntu images on this machine, each with their own home dir. I am trying to consolidate them on a redundant iscsi NAS. This seems like it should be straight forward. It eventually locks up the machine.
I mount the 300GB `iscsi lun` as `/newhome`. It is formatted and the copy does start out successful then it degrades.
the cmd itself is `cp -rp /home/user/* .` where `.` is my current dir which is where the iscsi extent is mounted to.
I see, in `syslog` multiple copies of the following sequence.

```
    Jul 14 11:01:23 cor8910 kernel: [ 2925.828199] Fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed!
    Jul 14 11:01:23 cor8910 kernel: [ 2925.828200] BUG: kernel NULL pointer dereference, address: 0000000000000009
    Jul 14 11:01:23 cor8910 kernel: [ 2925.828201] #PF: supervisor write access in kernel mode
    Jul 14 11:01:23 cor8910 kernel: [ 2925.828201] #PF: error_code(0x0002) - not-present page
    Jul 14 11:01:23 cor8910 kernel: [ 2925.828202] PGD 0 P4D 0 
    Jul 14 11:01:23 cor8910 kernel: [ 2925.828203] Oops: 0002 [#5664066] SMP PTI
    Jul 14 11:01:23 cor8910 kernel: [ 2925.828204] CPU: 6 PID: 22429 Comm: MainThread Tainted: P    B D W  O L    5.4.0-122-generic #138-Ubuntu
    Jul 14 11:01:23 cor8910 kernel: [ 2925.828205] Hardware name: Dell Inc. XPS 8910/0WPMFG, BIOS 1.0.4 05/30/2016
    Jul 14 11:01:23 cor8910 kernel: [ 2925.828206] RIP: 0010:blk_flush_plug_list+0x7d/0x110
    Jul 14 11:01:23 cor8910 kernel: [ 2925.828207] Code: 49 bd 22 01 00 00 00 00 ad de 49 8b 44 24 10 48 39 c3 74 27 49 8b 4c 24 10 49 8b 54 24 18 48 8b 45 c0 4c 89 79 08 48 89 4d c0 <48> 89 02 48 89 50 08 49 89 5c 24 10 49 89 5c 24 18 48 8b 45 c0 49
    Jul 14 11:01:23 cor8910 kernel: [ 2925.828207] RSP: 0018:ffff9f0e4e8bfe68 EFLAGS: 00010006
    Jul 14 11:01:23 cor8910 kernel: [ 2925.828208] RAX: ffff9f0e4e8bfe70 RBX: ffff9f0e4e8bfec0 RCX: ffff92d6dde21800
    Jul 14 11:01:23 cor8910 kernel: [ 2925.828209] RDX: 0000000000000009 RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: ffff9f0e4e8bfeb0
    Jul 14 11:01:23 cor8910 kernel: [ 2925.828210] RBP: ffff9f0e4e8bfeb0 R08: 000000001b02a505 R09: ffffffffb01a7bec
    Jul 14 11:01:23 cor8910 kernel: [ 2925.828210] R10: ffffffffb01a0228 R11: ffff9f0e4e8bfd60 R12: ffff9f0e4e8bfeb0
    Jul 14 11:01:23 cor8910 kernel: [ 2925.828211] R13: dead000000000122 R14: dead000000000100 R15: ffff9f0e4e8bfe70
    Jul 14 11:01:23 cor8910 kernel: [ 2925.828212] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff92d77eb80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
    Jul 14 11:01:23 cor8910 kernel: [ 2925.828213] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
    Jul 14 11:01:23 cor8910 kernel: [ 2925.828214] CR2: 0000000000000009 CR3: 0000000e45d0c004 CR4: 00000000003606e0
    Jul 14 11:01:23 cor8910 kernel: [ 2925.828214] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
    Jul 14 11:01:23 cor8910 kernel: [ 2925.828215] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000fffe0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
    Jul 14 11:01:23 cor8910 kernel: [ 2925.828216] Call Trace:
    Jul 14 11:01:23 cor8910 kernel: [ 2925.828218]  schedule+0x75/0xb0
    Jul 14 11:01:23 cor8910 kernel: [ 2925.828221]  do_exit.cold+0x46/0xa7
    Jul 14 11:01:23 cor8910 kernel: [ 2925.828224]  rewind_stack_do_exit+0x17/0x20
    Jul 14 11:01:23 cor8910 kernel: [ 2925.828228] RIP: 0033:0x7fd8340b7a7b
    Jul 14 11:01:23 cor8910 kernel: [ 2925.828231] systemd-journald[371]: /dev/kmsg buffer overrun, some messages lost.
    Jul 14 11:01:23 cor8910 kernel: [ 2925.828232] Code: c3 48 8b 15 17 34 0d 00 f7 d8 64 89 02 b8 ff ff ff ff eb c2 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 90 f3 0f 1e fa b8 1c 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d e5 33 0d 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48
    Jul 14 11:01:23 cor8910 kernel: [ 2925.828233] RSP: 002b:00007fffa0e6e7f8 EFLAGS: 00000202 ORIG_RAX: 000000000000001c
    Jul 14 11:01:23 cor8910 kernel: [ 2925.828236] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00007fffa0e6e820 RCX: 00007fd8340b7a7b
    Jul 14 11:01:23 cor8910 kernel: [ 2925.828237] RDX: 000000000000000f RSI: 00000000007fd000 RDI: 00007fffa0673000
    Jul 14 11:01:23 cor8910 kernel: [ 2925.828238] RBP: 00007fd833dc2768 R08: 00000000ffffffff R09: 0000000000000000
    Jul 14 11:01:23 cor8910 kernel: [ 2925.828240] R10: 00007fd82884d325 R11: 0000000000000202 R12: 00007fd8315500a0
    Jul 14 11:01:23 cor8910 kernel: [ 2925.828241] R13: 00007fd833dc2718 R14: 00007fd833dd9200 R15: 00007fd833dd92a0
    Jul 14 11:01:23 cor8910 kernel: [ 2925.828242] Modules linked in: rfcomm xt_CHECKSUM xt_MASQUERADE xt_conntrack ipt_REJECT nf_reject_ipv4 xt_tcpudp iscsi_tcp libiscsi_tcp libiscsi scsi_transport_iscsi veth nf_tables_set nft_masq nft_chain_nat zfs(PO) zunicode(PO) zlua(PO) zavl(PO) icp(PO) zcommon(PO) znvpair(PO) spl(O) ebtable_filter ebtables ip6table_raw ip6table_mangle ip6table_nat ip6table_filter ip6_tables iptable_raw iptable_mangle iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 libcrc32c iptable_filter bpfilter nf_tables nfnetlink vhost_vsock vmw_vsock_virtio_transport_common vhost vsock bridge stp llc cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep binfmt_misc nls_iso8859_1 nvidia_uvm(O) nvidia_drm(PO) nvidia_modeset(PO) nvidia(PO) intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio coretemp kvm_intel kvm i915 crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel crypto_simd cryptd drm_kms_helper i2c_algo_bit glue_helper fb_sys_fops
    Jul 14 11:01:23 cor8910 kernel: [ 2925.828279]  syscopyarea sysfillrect rapl intel_cstate mei_hdcp iwlmvm mac80211 libarc4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi iwlwifi snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec btusb snd_hda_core cfg80211 btrtl btbcm joydev btintel 8250_dw snd_hwdep input_leds bluetooth snd_pcm ecdh_generic ecc snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi sysimgblt snd_seq mei_me mei snd_seq_device snd_timer snd dell_wmi soundcore dell_smbios dcdbas dell_wmi_descriptor mac_hid acpi_pad sparse_keymap wmi_bmof mxm_wmi sch_fq_codel ipmi_devintf ipmi_msghandler msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport sunrpc drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 uas usb_storage hid_generic usbhid hid crc32_pclmul nvme ahci libahci nvme_core intel_lpss_pci alx i2c_i801 intel_lpss mdio idma64 virt_dma video pinctrl_sunrisepoint wmi pinctrl_intel
    Jul 14 11:01:23 cor8910 kernel: [ 2925.828292] CR2: 0000000000000009
    Jul 14 11:01:23 cor8910 kernel: [ 2925.828293] ---[ end trace b0ab88c2c48452e1 ]---
```

current booted image HDD `20.04.3` SDA2
I've tried this from nvme image, 20.04 current fix level
I've tried this from SSD 22.04

A couple of things:
I am guessing this is a bug. current OS Ubuntu 20.04.3 current update level

Is there is vehicle to perform a bulk copy. My goal is to start with the oldest and apply progressively newer home dir contents.

Comment: - You are missing `-r` to include dirs.  - Please reconsider this and ONLY do this for the subdirectories in /home/$USER/ and you can do this by editing `~/.config/users-dirs.dirs` Doing this for the hidden files is going to break one of your systems at some point.

Comment: @Rinzwind Good catch, thank you! I updated the description to indicate cp -rp .... That was my omission. I also wanted to preserve ownership information.

Comment: rsync might be a better method. It has resume and you will get more info when it does crash.

Comment: @Rinzwind I've actually tried this with rsyc but in the past while the system doesn't freeze rsync does, presumably on files larger than its buffers. I also added --partial such that I can resume where it left off..also incremental. Would you elaborate on modifying user dirs and the admonition of hidden files. I actually do want them moved as a lot of the apps use hidden files for their profiles and runtime information. Im thinking at a minimum .thunderbird but there are others. Im not familiar with user-dirs. I've never had the necessity to use it.

Comment: When sharing the hidden files in /home/ ALL operating systems MUST act exactly the same otherwise you might have crashes due to incompatibility. `~/.config/users-dirs.dirs` has a text segment explaining how to use it.

Comment: @Rinzwind I should author a 2nd quest, after search to see if someone has already asked it. Some of your concerns, if not all, are mitigated by my specific use case. This common home will be used by a single user at a single machine. The specific machine/image may vary. The two problems I am trying to solve are home directory surviving a hardware failure as well as software failure. The number of software updates/upgrades layered are finite. Whether new hardware or software I want my working environment to survive intact. I hope you see where thos is heading.

Comment: @Rinzwind Whether I was using cp -rp or rsync the task would ultimately fail, either lock up the process, requiring cntrl-c, the os, requiring cntrl-alt-del,  the machine requiring  power recycling. Many times reboot would force an fsck or 1 sec, undiscernable msg re inodes. There were multiple subdirs I ended up excluding.  After an inordinate number of restarts it did complete. I don't know if the root cause was h/w, s/w, or f/w. The pc is 6-8 years old the last bios update was 2016. I've replaced and fully populated main memory, added nvme adn, most recently WD SSD as there's been

Comment: @Rinzwind random, intermittent indications of failing memory in nvme hence the SSD. But the nvme has a year+ of sodtware and projects. I decided to bag the prior saved off copies of home dirs in favor of having them avail as existing subdirs of the existing HDD which I mount remotely and just use my 'current' home but make it resilient and survivable. Next is how to make the toolbar resilient.

Answer (score 0):

This actually was a hardware issue which was only sporadically seen when using rsync. It was bad memory. I ended up sending the unit back to Dell who replaced the memory as well as the disk. It was not clear there was anything wrong with the disk beyond it did not have Windows on it.

Thank you to all who responded. I eventually did get the home directory copied to a lun and updated twice daily. Unfortunately mounting an ISCSI drive as /home, while possible, noticeably impacts performance.