# How do I, if at all, configure a user environment that is not tethered to a physical machine with a Ubuntu image installed

Tags: mount, home-directory, administration, iscsi

This is the genesis of
[How do I copy a local home dir to an iscsi mounted home directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1418732/how-do-i-copy-a-local-home-dir-to-an-iscsi-mounted-home-directory)

I have read, over the last decade, that while Ubuntu is pretty respectable with upgrade in place it is not foolproof indefinitely. And, additionally, hardware fails. The above referenced question is part of the solution but not necessarily complete.

In the event hardware fails, either disk, nvme, ssd, cpu, etc, fails, is there a solution such that replacing the machine or any part of it, one can remount  and reboot to the last used user environment. Is moving /home to an NFS or ISCSI device and remounting from it sufficient to restore the users work environment. I've never been a sysadmin and I imagine, at least in a Windows env it is possible. Is it in Ubuntu env and, if so, how?

Should/can /etc/ be saved? fstab, hosts, iscsi config among whatever else.

Comment: @user535733 I wouldn't say 'new learner' is esp apt but. I never worked in a sysadmin group but I've been in software dev organization for close to 50 yrs. If one's machine failed the sysadmin would fix or replace your machine and you'd be back to where you were prior to failure. The goal therefor is to have as little user specific information local to the machine as possible. My previously mentioned question dealt with backing up home which was problematic but, ultimately I have it on a remote lun. This ? is and here is the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: @user535733 I entertained backing up /etc but that likely is problematic. It would be easier to install open-iscsi and script adding local host file, discovering local luns, marking  node startup as automatic, and adding requisite fstab entries. Now I am guessing ergo asking someone who does this for a living.